# Azure Web API Authentication not working

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api

I have configured azure web api and my react app and that is working perfectly until I turn On Azure authentication as shown in below screenshot. Once I turn it on I am getting 
"**You do not have permission to view this directory or page.**" for all my web apis.

And this message is from Azure and Authentication type is advanced in azure .

[image]

Am I missing anything here ? (My client want's it to be turned on. )

Answer (score 0):

Easy Auth won't validate automatically the token for you. You need to add the JWT Validation to your webapi:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-manual-jwt-validation/